# How could I store multiple values to one reusable variable - reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on small react app and my dropdowns looks like this:

```
<CustDropdown 
disabled={
      isPlayerLoaded ||
      this.state.players.length === 0 || 
      !this.state.players 
    }
/>
```

Issue here is I would like to get rid of this code after `disabled`. Is it possible to store it to somevariable which might be used here after `disabled`.

So disabled would look like `disabled = isPlayerDisabled`.

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the `return` statement declare a `const` to hold the result of the logic operation. You can also use `destructuring assignment` to make your code more clean

```
const { players } = this.state
const disabled = isPlayerLoaded || players.length === 0 || !players 

return <CustDropDown disabled={disabled} />
```

Comment: logical OR instead of bitwise OR

Comment: it was a typo bro